# How to handle colon de-limited strings in apex_util.string_to_table function, while moving values from left to right in a shuttle in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

For example: consider there are 4 strings like a:b, c, d and e arranged in an array VC_ARR2 type
{a:b:c:d:e}
Here a:b is a single string... but while moving the string a:b, from left to right and trying to save then the data is moving back to the left side. And the data is saving as two separate records in the database, like "a" is in separate record and "b" in separate. I want the data to be stored in one record, like a:b

How should I handle this situation in page level in oracle apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not the way it is now. How will you distinguish what makes a *pair* out of `a:b:c:d:e`? Is it `a:b` or `c:d` or ...? No way, unless you change delimiter for your strings from colon to something else.